# OSX Re-Install : Disk not found

Tags: macos, hard-drive, installation

Yesterday, I made a big mistake, I killed a processus thinking that it was another. OSX freezed, had to shutdown it the wrong way (pressing the button). When i tried to start it back, login screen appeared, i typed in my password, started to load... But about half the bar, a big prohibitory sign appeared.

This morning, i start it pressing cmd-r, my disk is in the Disk Utility, but is full, not a single free byte. When i go in OSX installation, i've to unlock it using my session password, but then when i wan't to select it to install OSX back, i can't find it...

Is there any way for me to reinstall OSX that doesn't involve losing all my files ?

Thanks.

Comment: Tell us about your hardware! Is it a macbook, with an old fashioned HDD in it, it a retina one with the Apple-only SSD?

Comment: It's a late 2012 macbook pro with an old fashion 500gb HDD

Comment: Then you can take the harddisk out, put another disk in, install OSX on the new disk, copy all data from the other disk, and you're pretty sure that the old disk won't be harmed.